# "nicht einen einzigen Mann sehen" vs "keinen einzigen Mann sehen"

Tags: difference, usage

Aus dem [*Spiegel-Online*](http://www.spiegel.de/schulspiegel/wissen/bremer-projekt-kaempft-gegen-maennermangel-an-grundschulen-a-1010733.html):

> (a) "Eine große Zahl von Kindern geht durch die Bildungsinstitutionen und sieht nicht einen einzigen Mann", sagt Fantini.

Normalerweise würde ich

> (b) ... und sieht **keinen** einzigen Mann.

erwarten. Es scheint mir, dass sich "nicht" im Spiegel-Satz nicht auf "einen einzigen Mann", sondern auf "sieht" bezieht. (Sonst müsste man (b) verwenden.) Wenn so, gibt es einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung zwischen den beiden Sätzen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Formulierungen sind weitgehend äquivalent. In (a) wird *nicht* das Verb verneint, sondern *einen*. Als explizitere Variante von *keinen* hat *nicht einen* genau dieselbe Bedeutung, betont aber die Negation stärker. Dabei liegt, wenn man den Satz ausspricht, die Betonung allerdings nicht auf *nicht,* sondern ausschließlich auf *einen*.

Grund dafür ist, dass *keinen* manchmal nicht wörtlich zu verstehen ist, sondern u. U. auch dann verwendet wird, wenn die Anzahl viel kleiner ist als erwartet. *Nicht einen* stellt klar, dass die Aussage wörtlich zu verstehen ist, die Kinder also nicht einmal einen einzigen Mann sehen. *Keinen einzigen* hat natürlich dieselbe Funktion. In *nicht einen einzigen* sind beide Klarstellungen kombiniert, wohl um diese überraschende Behauptung besonders zu unterstreichen. (Es ist auch möglich, dass im Sprachgefühl des Verfassers infolge der allgemeinen Abnutzung starker Formulierungen bereits *nicht einen* und *keinen einzigen* jeweils für sich genommen im übertragenen Sinne verwendet werden kann.)

Man kann es noch weiter treiben: Selbst "noch nicht einmal einen einzigen" ist eine durchaus gängige Wortfolge.

Answer (score 2):

Version A legt die Betonung des Satzes darauf, dass kein Mann zu sehen ist.

Es geht nicht darum, was die Kinder sehen, sondern dass keine Männer zu sehen sind.

Es wird mehr darauf hingewiesen, dass **nicht mal einer** zu sehen ist, während Version B eher die Betonung legt auf was die Kinder sehen; uns B würde auch die Interpretation zulassen, dass es Zufall wäre und sie schon einen sehen hätten können.